# Linking Non terminals for back patching

Tags: bison

```
idlist  : idlist ',' ID {
                         $$.str=$3.str;
                         $$.ptr=(idtype*)&$1;
                        }
        | ID            {
                         $$.str=$1.str;
                         $$.ptr=NULL;
                        }
```

idlist is here of type idtype. I'm a newbie to Yaac. Am I doing something stupid because, My code is looping through a single id. when I use this at one level up.

So here the grammar has type after  the ID. I could use a stack to do that, but i thought this was cute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking the address of `$1`, which is a local temporary that exists only for that rule action.  So after the action completes, it goes away, leaving `$$.ptr` dangling, and pointing at memory that's going to be reused for something else.